# How does system() exactly work in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I've been reading its man page but haven't yet been successful in figuring out how it works. On calling system(), is a new child process forked and the shell binary exec()-ed in it? That may be a stupid guess though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, system() is essentially a fork() and exec() "sh -c" for the passed command string.  An example implementation (from eglibc, recently forked from glibc) can be found [here](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_9/libc/sysdeps/posix/system.c?rev=7350&view=markup).

Comment: system() use posix_spawn now in 2021.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, system("foo bar") is equivalent to execv("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "foo bar"]).

Comment: Posix requires that system() ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT and block SIGCHLD.