# How is system() function of stdlib.h file implemented in linux?

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does system() exactly work in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872230/how-does-system-exactly-work-in-linux)

For the sake of my curiosity,
I want to know that how does system() function spawn the process and its internal implemenation ?
Is is using fork , exec internally ?

Comment: Try also: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Debian box it uses clone() that itself calls sys_clone(). You can use strace to look at system calls.

Comment: Use `strace -f` to trace child processes too.

Comment: system internally uses fork() and exec() and its blocking call.