# Perl system() call escapes metacharacter

Tags: bash, shell, perl

My student wrote this simple program that calls system to cat some files, but for some reason it escapes the * metacharacter when it shouldn't.

```
#!/opt/anaconda3/bin/perl

# catfastq.pl

# the following 'use' just makes the script print warnings and controles variable scoping (i.e. I have to place 'my' before a new variable declaration)
use warnings;
use strict;

# define array of letters that you will use in the file names
my @letter = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Z');

# store full path to where fastq files are in 'readdir' variable
my $readdir = '/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun';

# store name of output directory in 'outdir' variable
my $outdir = '/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/combined';

# make output directory if it doesn't exist already
if (!-d $outdir)
{
        if (!mkdir($outdir))
        {
                print STDERR "Couldn't create output directory\n";
                exit 1;
        }
}

# loop through each element of the 'letter' array (note that the element will be stored in the 'lib' variable)
foreach my $lib (@letter)
{
        # the system function executes a command just like if you were to type it in the bash terminal

        # concatenate R1 files
        system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*R1_001.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R1.fastq");

        # concatenate R2 files
        system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*R2_001.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R2.fastq");
}

exit;
```

This is the output:

```
cat:/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1S*R2_001.fastq: No such file or directory 
cat:/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1T*R1_001.fastq: No such file or directory 
cat:/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1T*R2_001.fastq: No such file or directory 
cat:/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1U*R1_001.fastq: No such file or directory 
cat:/home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1U*R2_001.fastq: No such file or directory
```

Files are there (for example)

```
RSFV1S_S37_L005_R1.fastq  RSFV1S_S37_L005_R2.fastq  RSFV1S_S37_L006_R1.fastq  RSFV1S_S37_L006_R2.fastq  RSFV1S_S37_L007_R1.fastq  RSFV1S_S37_L007_R2.fastq
```

[image]
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Re "*for some reason it escapes the * metacharacter when it shouldn't.*", It doesn't. `sh` doesn't expand `*` when there are no matches.

Comment: Exactly, have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458104/how-do-i-pass-a-wildcard-parameter-to-a-bash-file

it is your shell that will do the magic of interpreting wildcards and not the `cat` command for the cat command it is completely transparent, it just receives a list of arguments from its parent process, the `shell`!!! In your case you are directly calling the cat command from the perl process! Also check: http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm

Comment: @Allan is mistaken. You are involving the shell. It simply doesn't expand `*` if there are no matches. This can be seen using `sh -c 'echo nonexistent*'`

Comment: @ikegami: really? So do you mean there is an intermediate step with a shell generation before the command is called and after it returns? I would like to know more about it!

Comment: @Allan, No, I'm saying `system(EXPR)` is short for `system('/bin/sh', '-c', EXPR)` (There is an optimization that avoids the shell if EXPR contains no shell metacharacters other than whitespace, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: @ikegami: Nice!!! I learned something today with this:

`system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*R1_001.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R1.fastq") is the same as system('/bin/sh', '-c', "cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*R1_001.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R1.fastq")` deleting my answer! :-) Thank you a lot for this I had no idea ;-) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872230/how-does-system-exactly-work-in-linux

Comment: @ikegami there are matches tho :/

Comment: Your shell disagrees, and I trust it more than you. You might be looking in the wrong directory, or there might be characters you don't see in their name. Or maybe they are there, but a permission issue prevents them from being seen, though I think that would give a different error message.

Comment: @ikegami right on. prt sc added.

Comment: What's the output of `echo /home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1S*R2_001.fastq`

Comment: /home/data/madzays/finch_data/firstrun/RSFV1S*R2_001.fastq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166862/discussion-between-madza-yasodara-farias-virgens-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl is not escaping the `*`. The issue is that `sh` doesn't find any matches, and it only expands `*` when it finds a match.

```
$ echo fi*le
fi*le

$ touch file

$ echo fi*le
file
```

The problem is that you are using

```
system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*R1_001.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R1.fastq");

system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*R2_001.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R2.fastq");
```

when you should be using

```
system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*001_R1.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R1.fastq");

system("cat ${readdir}/RSFV1${lib}*001_R2.fastq > ${outdir}/RSFV1${lib}_R2.fastq");
```

Comment: Thank you! You were right when you said "Your shell disagrees, and I trust it more than you"! ;)